# Is the only way to Delete / Put object from REST trough cloud code ? (Cors issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

Here is a code of AngularJs with a Parse.com backend. It's supposed to fetch objects, get their id, then delete them all.

```
prosFactory.getFavoriteActivity(parseUserId, objectId )

                    .success(function(data) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {    
                            prosFactory.deleteFavoriteActivity(data.results[i].objectId )
                                .success(function() {
                                    console.log("deleted");
                                }).error(function(status) {
                                    alert(status);
                                }
                            );
                        }

                    }).error(function() {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                )
```

It activates this elsewhere:

```
deleteFavoriteActivity: function (objectId) {
                return $http.delete(favoritesActivityUrl + '/' + objectId, parseCredentials);
            }
```

This throws this I guess CORS browser error:

```
OPTIONS https://api.parse.com/1/classes/Favorites/TL4XN1NfEW No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What is strange is that I perform in other place in code similar Delete REST function, and don't get this error at all.
Is there any way to have this not trigger error, without running this code from Parse cloud hosted file ? Or is running that from cloud the only option ?

Comment: This error just started happening to us this week, though we haven't identified a relevant change to our code. For the moment, we've worked around it using the Javascript API. https://parse.com/questions/creating-a-role-cors-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin may be relevant.

Comment: today the problem vanished, without changing anything to the code.
Do you confirm this ? I'm going to open an issue at Parse.com

Comment: We see the problem coming and going this morning. Perhaps parse.com is working on it. If you do file a bug report, please post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely a problem on Parse's end:
https://www.parse.com/questions/cors-issue-appears-and-disappear-spontaneously

I'm quite upset as this was not announced in their status page altough it's a known problem, which resulted in hours wasted in bug research.